# Objective-c: Open URL in WebView (Mac)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, webkit

I'm having a problem with opening a URL in WebView. Haven't programed with objective-c in awhile and it looks like what I'm coding has depreciated. The application opens, loads the URL but crashes with this error

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)

I originally used this to help me program in the past: [How to load URL on launch in a WebView (OSX project)?

Here's the code:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    WebView *myWebView;
}

@property

(retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet WebView *myWebView;


@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSString *urlText = @"http://google.com";
    [[self.myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlText]]];
    return;
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

@end
```

I receive a warning in AppDelegate.m before I build

> Autosynthesized property 'myWebView' will use synthesized instance
>   variable '_myWebView', not existing instance variable 'myWebView'

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Delete your declaration of `WebView *myWebView;` insider your curly brackets, that's not necessary.

Comment: Made that as an answer so others will know this question is answered, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your declaration of `WebView *myWebView;` insider your curly brackets, that's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For second part of your question, that is for opening a URL in webview there is a fork of phoneGap(http://phonegap.com) called Macgap available. you can check that out here, http://github.com/maccman/macgap

Comment: Really cool! I'm looking to build a Twitter equivalent app with web technologies and this might just help. Thanks for sharing!